# What is the code for doing a crowdsale without a functional coin code?

Tags: solidity, ico

How can i write a crowdsale code which will enable me to send all the users that backed the project only a private key and in 6 more month to send them their tokens .
what is the code for that?  the code in the site enable doing crowdsale only if the token code is set and ready..

Comment: Look at the `now` word in Solidity to implement a time limit. And to enable the crowdsale, can't you just set a threshold that makes the sale official once it is crossed?

Answer (score 1):

ico.iconomi.net is doing something similar currently.
Their approach is to register people on a webapplication, generate a key where the investor can send in the ether and forward it to the ico address. For generating the address one can use for example [light-wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) together with [web3 hook](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider).
When you release the tokens you can ask the investor to insert a public address in a form and release the tokens there with a function like:

```
 function release(address a, amount) {
     if (msg.sender != contractOwner) throw;
     balance[a] = amount;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend looking at

https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico

or

https://github.com/airalab

They have quite a few contracts that will help you to solve your problem.